# I can't Inserted columns using select query

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to insert rows in a table A of 5 columns, 
the 2 first columns are selected from another table B, and the rest of the columns are giving

```
insert into A(a,b,c,d,e)
values ((select a1,b2 from B where a1=X) ,'c2' ,d2,e2);
```

Comment: `insert into ta (c1, c2...) select ... from ...`

Comment: thanks for the response,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `insert . . . select` syntax:

```
insert into A(a, b, c, d, e)
    select b.a1, b.b2, 'c2', d2, e2
    from B b
    where b.a1 = X;
```

Comment: In my case , c2, d2 and e2 aren't in my table B , the are some giving values

Comment: Hence the **b.** a1 to indicate you are getting values from a table.

Comment: yes I tried it as you describe it, and it worked,
and I shouldn't add values, because select do the work